# Entity Framework - Setting a "Nullable" integer to null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

I have a table in my DB called `Login`. In this table I have an attribute called `Head_ID`, which is nullable.

Basically, you can have a chief, or you ARE the chief. In the case that you're the chief, the `Head_ID` should be null. In my application I have the possibility to change one's chief (Coworker changes chief, chief gets downgraded and get's a chief above him), but this `int` won't be set to

**Service.cs**

```
public int EditLogin(LoginDTO login)
    {
        try
        {
            var dbLogin = DAO.HourRegInstance.Login.Single(x => x.ID == login.Id);
            dbLogin.Name = login.Name;
            dbLogin.Username = login.Username;
            if (login.Head_Id == 0)
            {
                //Doesn't work
                dbLogin.Head_ID = null;
            }
            dbLogin.Role_ID = login.Role_Id;
            DAO.HourRegInstance.SaveChanges();
            return 1;
        } catch(Exception e){
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

**Login.cs**

```
public partial class Login
{
    public Login()
    {
        this.HourRegistrationConfirmed = new HashSet<HourRegistrationConfirmed>();
        this.HourRegistrationConfirmed1 = new HashSet<HourRegistrationConfirmed>();
        this.Login1 = new HashSet<Login>();
        this.LoginProject = new HashSet<LoginProject>();
    }

    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public long Role_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> Head_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<HourRegistrationConfirmed> HourRegistrationConfirmed { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<HourRegistrationConfirmed> HourRegistrationConfirmed1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Login> Login1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Login Login2 { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LoginProject> LoginProject { get; set; }
}
```

How does one accomplish such task?

Comment: What do you mean by '//Doesn't work', do you get an error?

Comment: `dbLogin.Head_ID = null;` should work fine. Do you get an exception?

Comment: @Detilium if all else fails, restart

Comment: _[Have You Tried Turning It Off And On Again?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8)_

Answer (score 0):

**Solved the problem on my own.**

I'm not sure what caused this problem, but after a restart of the service, everything seems to work alright now. Maybe just Entity Framework being Entity Framework?